# UE4 import Animation during runtime

Tags: animation, runtime, unreal-engine4, fbx

I wanna know if it's possible or if anyone already worked on this function.

Basically what I want to do is using the Assimp library to import FBX& Animation inside, when import the FBX file there is an Animation inside, but don't really know how to use this Animation to convert what I can use to trigger it.

Is anyone have any idea about it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using the Assimp library in UE4 is fairly straightforward.  Copy the dll into “YourGame/Binaries/Win32 or Win64/” on Windows for example, and then you need to import the includes header source, which you can do in the main game library or create a separate plugin for it.  Then under your Build.cs file add the line PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "assimp-vc140-mt.lib"));

The steps are the same if you want to create a separate plugin for it.  As far as the animations go UE4 is using fbx in the background, so I can tell you from experience that you can get vertex transforms and apply them directly to UE4 mesh.  I would look into using UProceduralMeshComponent for this though, that is what it's made for.

The Unreal Forums have a couple guides on doing exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think i wasn't clear enough,  the step to import FBX and use Procedural Mesh to display the mesh is done on my side. 
My main purpose for this post is to know how to import skeletal mesh and Animation inside this FBX file. When I try to import the FBX file, I can see there is a Animation inside FBX, but I don't know how to handle it and play it during runtime.(ex: Import a "Helicopter", trigger Animation from "Helicopter", then the Helicopter rotor start to spinning)

Comment: Yes, this is where the format of the animation is simply a bunch of time based transforms for each bone in the mesh, I'm sure Assimp has a method of reading these values, then you simply iterate through each bone and apply the same transform to the procedural mesh component bone.  You will probably need some way of managing the time otherwise the animations may play faster than you would expect.  The nice thing is that the bones do not need the same names, in my experience Unreal doesn't do a lot to convert from fbx to it's uasset format so you just simply iterate over the bones.

Comment: That's would be really nice if I can use assimp library import and play Animation during rutnime, kind of know what's your meaning, thanks a lot for your information, but I still need to check how to implement